# Adding a link to an image in a list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image in a ul list clickable, here's my code so far. The paragraph is clickable but not the image.

```
<ul>
        <a href="/movies/test/"><li>
            <img src="/images.png" alt="">
        <p>test info</p></li></a>        
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. The structure should be:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/movies/test/">
       <img src="your image here" alt="">
        <p>test info</p>
     </a>      
   </li>  
</ul>
```

The image and text will all then be a single link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way;

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <a href="/movies/test/">
        <img src="/images.png" alt="">
        <p>test info</p>
      </a>
  </li>       
</ul>
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w5jLktrL/